# How can I move paragraphs using python docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I would like to move paragraph ,the principle is that there should be no text after the tables so I want a program that moves all the paragraphs after the tables to the top

[image]

do you have any idea how i can  do that ?

Thanks in advance